# How to scrape links that do not have a href and not available in page source

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to use selenium web driver to extract data and i get to see that one of the links that i want to click does not have a href. The html tags i see in inspect element are also not available in the page source.I badly want the link to be clicked and proceed to the next page.

The anchor tag that i see during inspect is as below and this seems to be having a angular JS

< a id="docs" ng-click="changeFragment('deal.docs')">

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('URL here');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
username = driver.find_element_by_name('USERID')
username.send_keys('12345')
password = driver.find_element_by_name('PASSWORD')
password.send_keys('password')
#search_box.submit()
driver.find_element_by_id("submitInput").submit()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
lnum = driver.find_element_by_name('Number')
lnum.send_keys('0589403823')

checkbox = driver.find_element_by_name('includeInactiveCheckBox').click()
driver.find_element_by_id("searchButton").click()
time.sleep(5) 
driver.execute_script("​changeFragment('deal.docs')").click()
driver.quit()
```

I tried to use find element by xpath and script but both didnt work .

The url im trying access cant be shared as it can be accessed only through a specific network

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Yes , im getting this error as  below      
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Invalid or unexpected token